# Large or short classNames in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am working in a project in React which I am using Sass & Bootstrap.

We have custom classes like:

```
.font-primary-color {
  color: $color-blue;
}
```

And what we call 'component-classes' like:

```
.button-component {
  background-color: $btn-bg-color;
  border: $btn-bg-color solid $input-btn-border-width;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: $white;
  padding: $btn-padding-md;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
}
```

Which is the best practice?

1. Use less classNames per component? This will bring a *clean render* with a large 'component-class'.

or

2. Use more 'custom classes'? The result will be a large (sometimes huge) className in render. But a smaller 'component-class'. Also, this option will be great because we can globalize styles such as font-sizes, margins, paddings, etc.

I mean, both of them has its advantage, but I don't really think that this is quite cleaner:

`<h1 className="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">Some text</h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very **Opinion Based** question. I would say **Both**, But in suitable places.

**Tiny Short Classes**

These types of classes are common in **Bootstrap** and **Tailwind**. This will help us to apply styles in a very flexible way. But also too many classes will reduce the **Code Readability**.

**Specific Classes (Component)**

This will help to minimize classes and apply a set of styles to the particular **element**/**component**. But obviously not flexible.

---

**In React, Use Both**

One of the major advantages of **React** is **re-usable components**. When we say re-usable, The component is **standard**/**common** that can be appeared in many other places. In that case, using too many tiny classes will be messy.

So, Always use **Specific Component Classes** for common components of the application. And use **Tiny Short Classes** for some additional styles or rare components.

**In Other Hand,**
When a component exceeds 4 - 5 short classes, and if the component appears in many places in the app, Please use a component class as the wrapper of those short classes.